Wrong size of middle vert with kpfonts
Using the package kpfonts, the middle vertical bar is too large in some cases. Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left\{ a \middle\vert a' \right\}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}

I know that I can fix this by using kpfonts-otf, but I do not want to use lualatex or xelatex...

That's not good usage of \left \middle \right, but the issue needs an explanation.
In fontmath.ltx we find
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\vert}{\mathord}{symbols}{"6A}{largesymbols}{"0C}

The declaration is not modified by kpfonts. With Computer Modern at 10pt,  we see that your formula doesn't trigger larger size. Instead, it does with kpfonts and TeX chooses \big size.
The largesymbols fonts are, respectively, cmex10 and jkpex. The character at slot "0Cincmex10has a vertical length of 0.6pt, whereas injkpex` it has a much shorter length. This character is repeated enough times to cover the formula, according to some TeX parameters.
So for Computer Modern two replicas of the character suffice, but with kpfonts three are needed, making the final output overlong with respect to the braces.
Actually, it's the braces in jkpex at minimum size that are too short.
You might get the same choice as with Computer Modern if you reduce \delimiterfactor to 850.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\delimiterfactor=850

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left\{a\middle\vert a'\right\}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


But the best is not using \left \middle and \right to begin with.

Thanks, this is solving the issue. But why is it best not to use \left / \middle / \right (I thought they were designed for that purpose...)? If you mean to use \mathtools's \DeclarePairedDelimiter instead, that's what I do but the size was also wrong with that command.

@Arkandias because in so many cases they are excessively large, especially if used in the text, others, like here they do nothing more than clutter up your code.

@Arkandias As you discovered, the extensible delimiters tend to grow too much.
